# Report generation in web applications

Tags: ms-word, jasper-reports, ireport, xls

As part of my web application, i am using iReport tool to generate reports and its working fine but my doubt is, is it possible to generate xls type report in browser like pdf (we can show the pdf file in the browser)? Means I need to show reports in xls file or word document in the client machine, is it possible? Can anybody clear my doubt?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can search a lot of answers on this theme at SO.

Comment: which MVC/Framework are you using???

Comment: I am using struts1.3.i got the solution for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is a bit late, I'll try to give a generic answer

1. you can fetch your data to your local [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) server via JSON. 
   There is a sample of JsonDataSource in the 4.5.0 version of jasperreports at `*\demo\samples\jsondatasource`
2. to run report and receive output pdf, etc. you can use [REST API](http://jasperforge.org/espdocs/download.php?filename=/opt/jasper/www/espdocs/Documents/112/v4.2.1%20Documentation%20/JasperReports-Server-Web-Services-Guide.pdf&ctype=application/pdf) for Jasper Server

then you send output to end user